python print statement issue when running with mpi
I have a parallel python code (based on mpi4py) that I run with mpirun -n ....
I have a print statement in this code that conditionally uses end="\r" during the unrolling of the code, or end="\n" at the last step of the code (so I can keep the last version of the line before printing new stuff). This line is only printed by process 0.
So basically:
for i in range(N):
 
 < some stuff >
 
 if (mpi.rank == 0):
  if (i < N-1): end = "\r"
  else: end = "\n"
  print("things, more things", end=end)


When running the code in sequential mode, everything works fine
When running with mpi, the line only prints at the last step (so nothing shows on screen until the unrolling is done)
If I replace "\r" with "\n" I get the expected behavior, i.e. all the lines print one after the other
Adding sys.stdout.flush() does not help

Thanks in advance for your suggestions, I'm out of ideas.
python 3.8.9
mpi4py 3.1.6
openmpi 5.0.3
